# Are HttpContext.Current and ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) equal?

Tags: c#, httphandler

I am using httphandler. Is the `HttpContext` which is passed in ProcessRequest referencing `HttpContext.Current`? Are there any differences using any of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both represent the same object. Personally I prefer to use the one passed as argument in contrast to the static `HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score 0):

You could, theoretically, pass in any HttpContext and process it. But, the normal methodology is processing the context in use, or HttpContext.Current. So, more than likely you will use HttpContext.Current so you process the HttpContext you are currently using for a running web application.